# Como hacer que el proceso de lectura de EasyOcr sea mas rapido?

Tags: python, opencv, kivy

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en kivymd y openCV que lea caracteres en tiempo real, el problema es  que el lector trabaja a menos de 1 fps. Como puedo aumentar los fps? Al trabajar con easyocr.reader bajan mucho los fps y el filtro canny no ayuda con la velocidad

```
        # DISPOSITIVO DE VIDEO'
       
        #self.capture= cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.145:8080/video')
        self.capture= cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/ 33.0)

        return layout
    
    # USAR LA CAMARA Y ACTUALIZAR CONTINUAMENTE
    def update(self, *args):
        
        # LEYENDO LOS FRAMES CON OPENCV
        reader= easyocr.Reader(["es"], gpu= False)
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        #frame = frame[150:150+250, 300:300+250, :]

        start= time.time()

        #canny= cv2.Canny(frame, 100, 200)

        buf= cv2.flip(frame, 0).tostring()
        img_texture= Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt= 'bgr')
        img_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt= 'bgr', bufferfmt= 'ubyte')
        self.cam.texture= img_texture

        canny=  cv2.Canny(frame, 100, 200)
        result= reader.readtext(canny)

        for res in result:
            print("RES: ", res)

        
        end= time.time()
        fps= 1/(end-start)
        #print("FPS: ", fps)


if __name__== '__main__':
    DivisaApp().run()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes una GPU?

Comment: Saludos, quiero trabajar el proyecto sin usar gpu